# How to protect from modifying/alter webview cache file in android programmatically

Tags: android, caching, cookies, android-webview, browser-cache

I am creating an webview android app. while using our app, its creating cache files in default location.

while loading app at first time, i am saving all files in cache file, For next time, retrieving all files from same cache location, for fast access, instead of remote download.

so, In this moment, There is a possibilities to tamper my cache file in android mobile.
so, i want to protect or secure from modifying the cache files in my mobile( if suppose my mobile theft).

I have searched and saw few sites, i am unable to found exact solution, which i am expecting?

Note: I want to restrict/protect/secure the cache file altering or modifying from tamper/theft person.

any suggestion or solution would be appreciated.

Thanks Advance

Referred websites:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings

[Any option to restrict our Android application cache being cleared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273350/any-option-to-restrict-our-android-application-cache-being-cleared)

[Caching in Android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128952/caching-in-android-webview)

[Is it possible to access the WebView cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809483/is-it-possible-to-access-the-webview-cache)

[Encrypt the WebView Cache on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696628/encrypt-the-webview-cache-on-android)

Comment: I doubt there would be public API for accessing cache files.

Comment: "There is a possibilities to tamper my cache file in android mobile" -- not really. Your app can modify your cache contents. No other app can, except on rooted devices. End users cannot modify the cache contents either, except on rooted devices.

Answer (score -1):

If your application accesses sensitive data with a WebView, consider using the clearCache() method to delete any files stored locally. You can also use server-side headers, such as no-store, to indicate that an application should not cache particular content.

read it:

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips#WebView

Comment: As per my requirement, i have to store data in cache files and need to make secure from unauthorised modification. so, we are seaking solutions.